# Pass ng-model value to a function using ng-disabled

Tags: angularjs, typescript, dry

There are a lot of questions that are asking similar things but most are either unanswered or do not answer my particular question. It's possible my question has already been answered but that there is so much noise that I can't find it.

I've written a simple function to control whether a checkbox should be disabled or not.

#### HTML

```
<input type="checkbox"
       data-ng-model="dont_forget_to_change_this_every_time"
       data-ng-disabled="check_disabled(dont_forget_to_change_this_every_time)">
```

#### TypeScript

```
$scope.check_disabled = (is_checked): boolean => {
    result = compare_is_checked_with_dynamic_data(is_checked);
    return result;
};
```

However, every time I use it I have to set the model name in two places and I'm trying to implement the **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself principle. Following other suggestions, I've tried the following:

#### HTML

```
<input type="checkbox"
       data-ng-model="dont_forget_to_change_this_every_time"
       data-ng-disabled="check_disabled([
           dont_forget_to_change_this_every_time,
           this,
           $event,
           $element,
           $scope
       ])">
```

#### TypeScript

```
$scope.check_disabled = (data): boolean => {
    console.log(data);
    return false;
};
```

In my function I get the following passed into data:

```
[
    true/false,
    a copy of $scope,
    null,
    null,
    null
]
```

How can I get the value of `data-ng-model` without repeating the model name in the function call each time?

Comment: Would it be correct if I say that this is a `directive` kinda thing you are trying build here ?

Comment: @Searching Possibly. I didn't write the original code, only the code I've posted here, and I don't know how closely the original follows the Angular way of doing things. I suspect not very much and if I change it too much other things might break.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to get the element or model value inside the `check_disabled` function. I think best way to do it is writing you own directive which disables element based on `ng-model` value and your logic inside `compare_is_checked_with_dynamic_data`